# Sorting a list of ('String', int) by its int (Haskell)

Tags: sorting, haskell

I am brand new to Haskell, so I'm still learning a lot of things. I was given a list of name and age, and I need to sort them in both alphabetical order and in increasing order using their age. I managed to sort the list alphabetically, but I'm unsure how to do it using its age values. What can I change in the code below? Thank you for your help.

```
qsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
-- check to see if the list is empty
qsort [] = []
qsort [x] = [x] -- Single element list is always sorted
qsort [x, y] = [(min x y), (max x y)]
-- x is the pivot, left quicksort returns smaller sorted and right quicksort bigger sorted
qsort (x:xs) =
  qsort [a | a <- xs, a <= x] ++ [x] ++ qsort [a | a <- xs, a > x]


people=[("Steve",20),("Smith",31),("Kris",19),("Beth",21)]

main = do
  print(qsort people) -- sort alphabetically
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's simplify your function a bit. Both the `[x]` and `[x, y]` cases are redundant: they are completely captured by the `(x:xs)` case. So let's remove those.

```
qsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) =
  qsort [a | a <- xs, a <= x] ++ [x] ++ qsort [a | a <- xs, a > x]
```

Now, currently we assume that the type of our list and the type we're sorting by are the same. We call them both `a`. Let's instead have two types: `a` will be the type of our list and `b` will be the type we want to sort by. Only `b` has to satisfy `Ord`, and we'll need a function to convert an `a` into a `b` so we can sort our list. This is our desired type

```
qsort :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Our base case is basically the same, except that we ignore the function argument.

```
qsort _ [] = []
```

In our recursive case, we compare by applying the function `f :: a -> b` and *then* using `<=` or `>`.

```
qsort f (x:xs) =
    qsort f [a | a <- xs, f a <= f x] ++ [x] ++ qsort f [a | a <- xs, f a > f x]
```

Now we can sort by whatever `Ord` type we want. We can sort by the first element of a tuple

```
-- Note: (fst :: (a, b) -> a) is in Prelude
print (qsort fst people)
```

or the second

```
-- Note: (snd :: (a, b) -> b) is in Prelude
print (qsort snd people)
```

both by their natural sorting order.

If we want to sort in the opposite order (descending rather than ascending), we can use [`Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down) as our function. If we want to sort by some complex order, we can always use the [newtype pattern](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype).

Comment: It might be better to call the new function something else, like `qsortOn`. Then the original `qsort` can be easily defined as `qsort = qsortOn id`.